# How to call an array within an array value + foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a contact from that suppose to send emails to different people as the dropdown option.

The option values are defined in arrays with an array and I am battling to call the array value so the email can go to designated person.

**Arrays are defined here:**

```
if((isset($_GET['enquiry']) && $_GET['enquiry']=='Locate a dealer/distributor')||(isset($_POST['enquiry']) && $_POST['enquiry']=='Locate a dealer/distributor')){
    $chk_Locate=TRUE;
}

if(isset($_GET['enquiry']) && $_GET['enquiry'] == 'CC'){
    $query_recipients = array(array('Complaint', 'csm@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Suggestion', 'csm@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Compliment', 'csm@examplecompany.co.za'));
    $enquiry = '<input type="hidden" name="enquiry" id="enquiry" value="CC">';
}

else{
    $query_recipients = array(array('Locate a dealer/distributor', 'sales@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Technical support', 'technical@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Back orders', 'backorders@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Product enquiry', 'sales@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Catalog request', 'sales@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('New customer enquiry', 'sales@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Existing customers - logon', 'dealers@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Existing customers - orders', 'weborder@examplecompany.co.za'),
                            array('Report web problems', 'webmaster@examplecompany.co.za'));
}
```

**Loop**

```
foreach($query_recipients as $key => $val){ 
    if((isset($_POST['enquiry']) && $_POST['enquiry'] == $val[0])||(isset($_GET['enquiry']) && $_GET['enquiry'] == $val[0])){
        $selected = $val[0].' : '.$item;
        if($val[0]=='Existing customers - logon'||$val[0]=='Technical support'||$val[0]=='Catalog request'||$val[0]=='Product enquiry'||$val[0]=='New customer enquiry'||$val[0]=='Existing customers - orders'||$val[0]=='Catalog request')
```

**The code that calls them is:**

```
$_POST['recipient_email'] = $contact_email.','.$recpt_email;
    if(isset($ref_number)){
        $_POST['subject'] = 'Examplecompany Group: '.$ref_number.': '.$_POST['enquiry'];
    }else{
        $_POST['subject'] = 'Examplecompany Group: '.$_POST['enquiry'];
    }
    $_POST['sender_email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_POST['cc'] = $_POST['email'].', Examplecompany Group <Examplecompany.orders@gmail.com>';
    $_POST['body'] = '<p>Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>'
                        . '<p>Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'] . '</p>'
                        . '<p>Company: ' . $_POST['company'] . '</p>'
                        . '<p>Examplecompany Account No.: ' . $_POST['accnr'] . '</p>'
                        . '<p>Account No. verification: ' . $cust_verify . '</p>'
                        . '<p>Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>'
                        . '<p>Tel/cell: ' . $_POST['tel'] . '</p>'
                        . $_POST['enquiry'] . ': ' . $_POST['message'];

    if(Email::Send($_POST, NULL)){
        $message = 'Your feedback has been sent'.$cont_ref;
    } else {
        $message = 'There was an error sending your feedback';
    }
}
```

This is the line I suppose to use to call them  `$_POST['recipient_email'] = $contact_email.','.$recpt_email;` for now it works but it calls the last array `array('Report web problems', 'webmaster@examplecompany.co.za')` irrespective of chosen option.

Please help, if i can find a way to call the array values I believe my form with work according to plan.

There is a line that i dont understand

```
$enquiry_options .= '<option>'.$val[0].'</option>';
    $recpt_email = $val[1];
```

If the val is set to `$Val[1]` the form sends email to the last email address on arrays but if set to `$Val[0]` it doesnt.

Comment: Have you considered using key-value pairs instead of nested arrays? For example, `array('Complaint' => 'address_one@example.com', 'Suggestion' => 'address_two@example.com')`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thanks for input, i'll check it out and feedaback.

Comment: Thanks for input, yes I've tried that and the page does load. I am not the original coder and cant seem to know what the original coder assign 1 here: $recpt_email = $val[1];

Comment: Thanks @user113215 i've been cracking my heard with this code but no luck.

 Enquiry field is:

<div><label>Enquiry</label><div><select name="enquiry" id="enquiry" class="select"><option selected="selected"><?php echo $selected ?></option><?php echo $enquiry_options ?></select></div></div>

Comment: I moved my comments to an answer and provided some sample code. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider switching your array to use key-value pairs instead of nested arrays. (Refer to the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) documentation.)

```
$enquiry_choices = array(
    'Complaint' => 'csm@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Suggestion' => 'csm@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Compliment' => 'csm@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Locate a dealer/distributor' => 'sales@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Technical support' => 'technical@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Back orders' => 'backorders@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Product enquiry' => 'sales@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Catalog request' => 'sales@examplecompany.co.za',
    'New customer enquiry' => 'sales@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Existing customers - logon' => 'dealers@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Existing customers - orders' => 'weborder@examplecompany.co.za',
    'Web site problems' => 'webmaster@examplecompany.co.za',
);

// Optional: Sort the choices by name
ksort($enquiry_choices);
```

This makes it easy to get the e-mail address associated with the user's choice.

```
$enquiry = $_GET['enquiry'];
$enquiry_email = (array_key_exists($enquiry, $enquiry_choices) ? $enquiry_choices[$enquiry] : false);
```

It is also simple to generate the HTML for the dropdown list. (Refer to the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation.) Note that the code above that defines `$enquiry` must preceed the code below.

```
echo <<<HTML
<div>
    <label for="enquiry">Enquiry:</label>
</div>
<select name="enquiry" id="enquiry" class="select">
HTML;

foreach($enquiry_choices as $key => $value) {
    $selected = ($enquiry == $key ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    echo "<option$selected>$key</option>";
}

echo '</select>';
```